# Toggle output using Verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Can anybody explain this code to me?

```
module test(clk,a);
  input clk;
  output a;
  reg temp;
  initial begin
  temp  <= 1'b1;
  always @(posedge clk)
    a <= ~temp;
  end
endmodule
```

I wanted to write code such that for every clock cycle the value of 'a' alternated between '0' and '1'.

Answer (score 2):

```
module test(clk,temp);
  input clk;
  output reg temp;
  initial temp = 1'b1;
  always @(posedge clk)
    temp <= ~temp;
endmodule
```

Issue in your code that each clock you assign `a` with inverted value of `temp` which stays constant; and also put all this stuff into initial block. Use `temp` in the code above, you do not need any additional register.

Edit: agreed with comment to another answer poster, `initial` is used for simulation, within real hardware you will need reset input signal

```
module test(clk,temp,reset_n);
  input clk;
  input reset_n;
  output reg temp;
  always @(posedge clk or negedge reset_n)
    if(!reset_n) temp <= 1'b1;
    else temp <= ~temp;
endmodule
```

Comment: i agree that `temp` will be constant but , the code it self its saying syntax error..any idea

Comment: @SaiSiril Your `always` needs to be outside the `initial` block.

Comment: @SaiSiril would help if you tell where syntax error is, but I guess it is in `initial` line because there must be `=` instead of `<=`. I edited my answer.

Comment: 'Initial' blocks may be acceptable for FPGAs, depending on what tools you use. In any case it doesn't really matter - this circuit will work whatever the initial state is.

Answer (score 0):

If my verilog is not too rusty.

You start the module and define all the inputs, outputs and signals you are planning to use. Which is this part:

```
input clk;
output a;
reg temp;
```

You start the module with

```
Initial begin
```

You define your temp signal as a one.
1'b1 is Verilog syntax for a constant value that is a one bit number expressed in binary format with a value of one.
A bit value of zero would be expressed as 1'b0.

```
 temp  <= 1'b1;
```

at the next part you say, every time the clock has a positive edge toggle the bit which is in temp and write it to a
The ~ symbol represents bitwise negation. Each bit in the value is toggled

```
always @(posedge clk)
a <= ~temp;
```

Comment: It will also not work as expected: think what happens to `temp`. The `initial` is also problematic as it's not realisable in hardware (*maybe* in an FPGA). It should be done with a `reset` input.

Answer (score 0):

initial blocks only execute once at time=0.  if you want to use intitial, use it, but put your `always@` elsewhere, outside the initial block, which is defined by `begin... end`

and, yes, as others say, `initial` is for simulation only... for real HW, use a reset to "initialize" a register

Answer (score 0):

It helps other to explain both what you expected (you did), and what you actually saw (syntax error).

The problem with your code is you have an `always` construct where only procedural statements are allowed. The `always` construct instantiates a process to execute procedural code, but it is not a procedural statement itself. The `initial` construct also creates a process, but is not a procedural statement. You may want to read [this discussion](https://verificationacademy.com/forums/systemverilog/aalways-block-task#reply-60952).

The other problem with your code is you are trying to make procedural assignments to the wire `a`, which is not allowed. See [this post](http://go.mentor.com/wire-vs-reg) for a complete explanation.

What you wanted to write is:

```
module test(input wire clk,
            output reg a);
  initial a = 1;
  always @(posedge clk)
    a <= ~a;
  end
endmodule
```

The next issue is if you want to synthesize this code into hardware, does your tool support an initial state for `a`, or will you need a separate reset signal to do that.